# Single page app with high number of images working extremely slow on iOS8 safari/Webview

Tags: webview, uiwebview, ios8, hybrid-mobile-app

We are working on a WebView (not WKWebView, yet) app, are are observing that the app runs extremely slow on iOS 8. The same app runs smooth on lower versions of OS like iOS7 and iOS6. So we tried it in safari on iOS8 and the performance is similar to iOS6 and 7.

The app is filled with images and many are high resolution. While trying to trace the issue (trial and error!) we reduced the sizes and resolutions of the images and the performance improved, but it is still not at par with versions 6 and 7.

We are unable to find any such issues reported elsewhere and are stuck. It would be great if we could get some pointers on this one.

Update: We tested again and it seems the app is almost as slow in safari as in the WebView on iOS8, while way fast (in comparison) on iOS7 and 6 (on both WebView and safari).

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about the devices you are using?

I can tell you what it is happening to us. We do HTML5 Games and since we updated our IPAD2, IPAD4, IPHONE4S to IOS8, we experiment a slow performance in the devices, specially the IPAD2.

I started to disable all the animation but the performance was still really bad. The image were still loaded in memory.

So finally we conclude that the IOS8 use more ram so the Safari can allocate less memory. We are going to improve it downloading the resolution of the images and scaling them to have the same size for the slowest device.

One advice, if the devices has a screen of 1024*700 like and IPAD2, images over the screen size use more memory than expected so avoid using image bigger than the screen size.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

My answer is another related question. In case it helps identify the issue.
I'm apparently not allowed to post a commment on the original question.

My multiple image htm page loads OK speed wise (20 or so small images). But they are not placed in the right locations. It is as if they have been shuffled.
Works fine on Mac Safari, worked fine on iOS7 Safari. Broken iOS8 Safari.

http://www.dependencysoftware.com/MobileProductList.htm
If you look carefully you will notice that the images do not match the descriptions, but on a Mac they work correctly. (also work on IE, Chrome, etc...)

It seems to get worse the further down you scroll.

Comment: Are you using the iOS Simulator, or an actual device? I have the same issue with images being swapped around randomly with the iOS 8 Simulator (either Safari or in-app webview), but it appears to be okay on a real iOS 8 device. It's a very strange problem and isn't always repeatable, but I'm hoping it's just a (very disconcerting) Simulator bug.